# Is it possible to call a Statistical Function from rxDataStep() in RevoScaleR (R Server)

Tags: r, microsoft-r

I am learning RevoScaleR (R Server) using the relevant EdX course.

I am tought that I can use rxDataStep() to feed functions or constructs passed to the 'transforms' argument with chunks of the data that are sitting on the disk, which rxDataStep converts to dataframes. rxDataStep() continues until all the data are processed and the transformation is completed.  So for example the following code creates a new column 'tip_percent':

```
rxDataStep(nyc_xdf, nyc_xdf,
           transforms = list(tip_percent = ifelse(fare_amount > 0 & tip_amount < fare_amount, round(tip_amount * 100 / fare_amount, 0), NA)),
           overwrite = TRUE)
```

My question is if I can use rxDataStep() to feed statistical functions such as lm() with chunks of data in cases when the data do not fit in the RAM.  A first attempt was not successful. I.e.:

```
rxDataStep(nyc_xdf, transforms = list(lm1 = lm(fare_amount ~ trip_distance)))
```

returns an error message:

```
ERROR: The sample data set for the analysis has no variables.
```

If rxDataStep() is not the way to go, what would be the right one?

Your advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To feed data to statistical functions, where data does not fit into memory, use the corresponding rx function. For your example you are using an XDF file, you would use RxXdfData() and rxLinMod() as so:

```
nyc_xdf <- RxXdfData("<path_to_xdf_file>", blocksPerRead = <number>)
lm1 <- rxLinMod(fare_amount ~ trip_distance, nyc_xdf)
```

Also, rxLinMod() can directly take an XDF file as such:

```
lm1 <- rxLinMod(fare_amount ~ trip_distance, data = "<path_to_xdf_file>",
            blocksPerRead = <number>)
```

Replacing  with the number of rows to be read from the XDF file per iteration will allow you to segment data into smaller memory chunks.

Please see ?rxLinMod and ?RxXdfData for documentation, as ever more advanced subsetting can be performed.